# Button seems unclickable through selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have been trying to click on the Submit button of the NAS website, but since the last update of the website, my code does not work anymore, and it is unable to click on the submit button.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Opens NAS Website
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.northamericanstainless.com/NAS_App/Surcharge1?language=E&type=F")
time.sleep(5)

# Click on Submit button
Submit = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="submitStylev2"]')
Submit.click()

# Wait time
time.sleep(5)

# Switches to pricing page
popup_handle = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(popup_handle)
```

It should have clicked the submit button on the website. This code used to work fine before the website underwent an upgrade.[This is the error I am receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7UUP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think after updating web site they changed location of button and I think you should change xpath of submit item like in the error they your code can't locate submit button try to check buttons location. Or this did not work try not to use xpath. I hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can not click the `Submit` button anymore is that the `Submit` button is present inside an `iframe`.

And to access it, you need to first switch to this iframe and then you'll be able to find it to perform a click.

Here's how you can do,

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.northamericanstainless.com/NAS_App/Surcharge1?language=E&type=F")

# wait for the iframe element to get loaded/located on the page
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe.surcharge-iframe')))

# switch to the desired iframe 
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe.surcharge-iframe'))

# click on submit button
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'submitStylev2').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thanks man it really worked. The iframe caused the error in my code

Comment: @AryanGupta, good to know that, If the provided answer solved your problem or helped you to fix the problem, please don't forget to upvote and mark it as accepted. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.